# コンテキストメニューから複数ファイルを開いた際のタブの順番について

Tags: emeditor

お世話になります。

エクスプローラー上でテキストファイルを複数選択し、コンテキストメニューからファイルを開いた際に
以前はタブの並びがファイル名の昇順で開けていたのですが、Ver.20.3.*以降タブの並びがバラバラになってしまうようになりました。

・例
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
004.txt
上記のようにファイルがあった場合に、全て選択し001.txtの上で右クリックしてコンテキストメニューから
ファイルを開くと、
｜001.txt｜002.txt｜003.txt｜004.txt｜
というようにファイル名の順にタブが開いていた。

手元にあったVer.20.2.2に戻して確認したところ、上記の通りファイル名の昇順で開くことができました。
よく上記のような使い方をするため、元の通りファイル名の順に開くように戻す方法があればご教示願います。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

まず EmEditor を起動してから、[ファイル] メニューの [開く] を選択して (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> を押して)、複数のファイルを選択してください。または、EmEditor のタブを右クリックして表示されるメニューから、[タブの整列] - [タブの自動整列] を選択してくと、自動的にタブの順番が指定した方法で並べ替えされます。

Comment: ご教示いただいた方法で並べ替えが出来ました。ありがとうございました。
また、事前にEmeditorを起動した状態であれば、エクスプローラーのコンテキストメニューから開いてもタブが昇順に並ぶことがわかりましたので、状況に応じて使い分けたいと思います。